# jQuery HTML Singular / Plural Text based on select multiple

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get the singular/plural for the text before the array, based on how many options are selected in the array.

For example, if only one selected option, it should be **Result in Category 1** 
if two or more are selected: **Results in Category 1, Category 2, and Category 3**

Working demo: https://jsfiddle.net/baidoct/xnjf9b0t/12/

```
$("#selectKat").change(function () {
  var ausbildungKatList = [];

  $.each($("#selectKat option:selected"), function () {
    ausbildungKatList.push($(this).val());
  });


   $('.asg-heading .dynamicKat').html("Result in " + humanLang(ausbildungKatList));

});
```

What's the best and elegant way to approach this?

Comment: Increment a counter variable inside your `$.each()` loop, or access `$("#selectKat option:selected").length` And then, `"Result"+(counter==1?"":"s")+" in ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Template literals (Template strings)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

All I have changed is the following line from:

```
$('.asg-heading .dynamicKat').html("Result in " + humanLang(ausbildungKatList));
```

to

```
$('.asg-heading .dynamicKat').html(`Result${ausbildungKatList.length > 1 ? 's': ''} in ${humanLang(ausbildungKatList)}`);
```

If using template literals you can use variables like so `${variableName}` or in this case a short if/else.

```js
function humanLang(arr) {
  if (arr.length <= 0) return '';
  if (arr.length === 1) return arr[0];
  const firsts = arr.slice(0, arr.length - 1);
  const last = arr[arr.length - 1];
  return firsts.join(', ') + ' and ' + last;
}

// Update Title
$("#selectKat").change(function () {
  var ausbildungKatList = [];

  $.each($("#selectKat option:selected"), function () {
    ausbildungKatList.push($(this).val());
  });

   $('.asg-heading .dynamicKat').html(`Result${ausbildungKatList.length > 1 ? 's': ''} in ${humanLang(ausbildungKatList)}`);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 class="asg-heading display-5">

  <span class="dynamicKat">Result in</span>
</h1>

<div class="form-floating">
  <label class="" for="selectKat">Ausbildungskategorie</label>
  <select class="form-select btn btn-neutral" multiple="multiple" id="selectKat">
    <option value="Category 1">Category 1</option>
    <option value="Category 2">Category 2</option>
    <option value="Category 3">Category 3</option>
    <option value="Category 4">Category 4</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

**Update:** Replace entire word with variable names

```js
function humanLang(arr) {
  if (arr.length <= 0) return '';
  if (arr.length === 1) return arr[0];
  const firsts = arr.slice(0, arr.length - 1);
  const last = arr[arr.length - 1];
  return firsts.join(', ') + ' and ' + last;
}

// Update Title

const singularResult = 'Result';
const pluralResult = 'Results';

$("#selectKat").change(function () {
  var ausbildungKatList = [];

  $.each($("#selectKat option:selected"), function () {
    ausbildungKatList.push($(this).val());
  });

   $('.asg-heading .dynamicKat').html(`${ausbildungKatList.length > 1 ? pluralResult : singularResult} in ${humanLang(ausbildungKatList)}`);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 class="asg-heading display-5">

  <span class="dynamicKat">Result in</span>
</h1>

<div class="form-floating">
  <label class="" for="selectKat">Ausbildungskategorie</label>
  <select class="form-select btn btn-neutral" multiple="multiple" id="selectKat">
    <option value="Category 1">Category 1</option>
    <option value="Category 2">Category 2</option>
    <option value="Category 3">Category 3</option>
    <option value="Category 4">Category 4</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: It works, HOWEVER, is there a way to do it by replacing the whole word, and not adding just "s" at the end? I might need another word (in a different language)

Comment: @Tudor sure you can. You can replace the string `'s'` or the empty string `''` with a javascript variable or whatever you need

Comment: @Tudor see the updated answer.

Comment: Thank you! One more offtopic question, related to the humanLang Function, if you select an option and then unselect it, it returns "... and undefined". Any idea why's that coming?

Comment: Thank you for the updated version, really simple and neat way to solve it! :)

Comment: @Tudor updated the two code snippets. Added another check `if (arr.length <= 0) return '';`  read like: return empty string `if (arr.length <= 0)`